# Discord.js Reaction Collector not listening for collector.on('collect')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with an AFK feature using Discord.js. When a user sends a message it will check if they are AFK and send a DM offering to turn off AFK if they react. I am trying to update to v12. It was working before updating, and now it seems to refuse to listen for any reactions. It will react to the message, but then any time I react it doesn't log it in the console.

```
message.author.send(noLongerAFKMessage).then(async function(msg) {
  try {
    await msg.react('✅');
    await msg.react('❌');
    const reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => {
      return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' || reaction.emoji.name === '❌';
    };
    // Use reaction filter to remove to remove the user from the database rather than an event
    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(reactionFilter, {
      time: 15000
    });
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, ReactionCollector) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${reaction.users.last().tag}`);
    });
    collector.on('end', _ => {
      msg.delete().catch(() => console.log('Tried deleting afk message that was already deleted'));
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

It throws no errors, it will run code after it sets up the reaction collector, I used console.log on the `collector`, and it seems to all work, it even deletes the message when the collector ends! I haven't found anything like this, and I'm really confused as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the *collect* event handler:

```js
collector.on('collect', (reaction, ReactionCollector) => {
  console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${reaction.users.last().tag}`);
});
```

There are 2 issues:

1. The *collect* event now passes a **MessageReaction** and **User** object in [Discord.js v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect), instead of an element and a **Collector** object like in [Discord.js v11](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.6.4/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-collect). This means that you need to change the parameters from `(reaction, ReactionCollector)` to `(reaction, user)`.
2. `reaction.users` no longer returns a Discord.js collection, but instead a [`ReactionUserManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager), which you have to access the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=cache) property of to get a [`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). This means that you need to change `reaction.users.last().tag` to `reaction.users.cache.last().tag`. Alternatively, since a **User** object is now passed, you can use `user.tag` instead.

**Here is the modified code:**

```js
collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. However, I realized something. I am working with Node's fs module, and have included my code in a separate file that uses module.export. When I comment out the lines that import the code and put the code in my main bot file, it works. Is there a way I can get it to be compatible with node's fs?

Comment: @ZachMontgomery You should be using `require()`, not fs. Put your code in a hastebin (with the Discord bot login token removed) and add a link here, so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zmontgo/506635f78b8dd8f3d7f42ae541dd8b78

Comment: @ZachMontgomery Have you tried using `readdirSync` instead of `readdir`?